# Can't insert a d3 chart on a bootstrap div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I need to put a d3 chart on a HTML div using bootstrap but I can't.
I managed to attach it on body, but I don't know why I cant inside a div.
I'm using a code like this for the script:

```
 var chart1 = d3.select("#chart1")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
```

and a simple way for html:

```
  <div id="chartline1"></div>
```

Here is all the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
        <title>Linee1</title>
            </head>

            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <body>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

            <script>
            var margin = {top: 130, right: 40, bottom: 45, left: 150},
                width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 505 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;


            var formatTime = d3.time.format("%e %B");

            var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
            var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
                .orient("left").ticks(3);


            var valueline = d3.svg.line()
                .interpolate("linear-open")
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

              var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.open); });


              var div = d3.select("#chartline1").append("div")   
                .attr("class", "tooltip")               
                .style("opacity", 0);  

            var chart1 = d3.select("#chartline1")
                .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", 
                          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
            function make_x_axis() {        
                return d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom")
                    .ticks(5)
                    }

            function make_y_axis() {        
                return d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left")
                    .ticks(3)
    }
    // Get the data
    d3.tsv("data/data2.tsv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
     d.open = +d.open; 
         });

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.close, `d.open); })]);` 



    //grid

          chart1.append("g")           
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

    chart1.append("g")         
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )



 chart1.append("g")            // Add the X Axis
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .style("font-size", "12px") ;



         chart1.append("text")             // text label for the x axis
        .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + (height+margin.bottom-3) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Tempo");


            chart1.append("g")         // Add the Y Axis
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .style("font-size", "12px");


chart1.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 70 - margin.left)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Valore");


    chart1.append("path")       
     .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data))
        .style("stroke-width", 5);

  chart1.append("path")         
        .attr("class", "line")
                .style("stroke", "#6f6f6f")
        .attr("d", valueline2(data))
        .style("stroke-width", 5);
        ;

//tooltip line 1

chart1.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                               
        .attr("r", 5.5)
        .style("fill", "#fff8ee")    
           .style("opacity", 1)      // set the element opacity
    .style("stroke", "#f93")    // set the line colour
 .style("stroke-width", 3.5) 

        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {   
d3.select(this).attr("r", 8).style("fill", "#f93").style("opacity", 1) ; 


            div.transition()        
                .duration(70)      
                .style("opacity", .8)

                 ;      
            div .html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 64) + "px"); 
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {     
        d3.select(this).attr("r", 5.5).style("fill", "#fff8ee"); 
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", 0) });



//tooltio line2
chart1.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                               
        .attr("r", 5.5)
        .style("fill", "#fff8ee")    
           .style("opacity", 1)      // set the element opacity
    .style("stroke", "#6f6f6f")    // set the line colour
 .style("stroke-width", 3.5) 

        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.open); })     
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            d3.select(this).attr("r", 8).style("fill", "#6f6f6f").style("opacity", 1) ; //il punto cambia al mousover (bellissmo)

            div.transition()        
                .duration(70)      
                .style("opacity", .7)
                .style("border", "1px");      
            div .html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 64) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
       d3.select(this).attr("r", 5.5).style("fill", "#fff8ee");  

            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });



//title

        chart1.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 6))             
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
        .style("font-size", "20px") 
        .style("text-decoration", "none")  
        .text("Modello 1: Serie (pochi dati) ");
});

</script>
<div id="chartline1" ></div>

</body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Declare the `div` before you run the script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must declare your div before you call the script. Put the script after it or encapsulate it in a function and call it on load.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                <title>Linee1</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
                    </head>


                    <body>

        <div id="chartline1" ></div>

        </body>

     <script>
                    var margin = {top: 130, right: 40, bottom: 45, left: 150},
                        width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 505 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;


                    var formatTime = d3.time.format("%e %B");

                    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
                    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

                    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
                        .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

                    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
                        .orient("left").ticks(3);


                    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
                        .interpolate("linear-open")
                        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                        .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

                      var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                        .y(function(d) { return y(d.open); });


                      var div = d3.select("#chartline1").append("div")   
                        .attr("class", "tooltip")               
                        .style("opacity", 0);  

                    var chart1 = d3.select("#chartline1")
                        .append("svg")
                            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append("g")
                            .attr("transform", 
                                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
                    function make_x_axis() {        
                        return d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(x)
                            .orient("bottom")
                            .ticks(5)
                            }

                    function make_y_axis() {        
                        return d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(y)
                            .orient("left")
                            .ticks(3)
            }
            // Get the data
            d3.tsv("data/data2.tsv", function(error, data) {
                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
                    d.close = +d.close;
             d.open = +d.open; 
                 });

                // Scale the range of the data
                x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
                y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return Math.max(d.close, `d.open); })]);` 



            //grid

                  chart1.append("g")           
                .attr("class", "grid")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(make_x_axis()
                    .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
                    .tickFormat("")
                )

            chart1.append("g")         
                .attr("class", "grid")
                .call(make_y_axis()
                    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
                    .tickFormat("")
                )



         chart1.append("g")            // Add the X Axis
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .style("font-size", "12px") ;



                 chart1.append("text")             // text label for the x axis
                .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + (height+margin.bottom-3) + ")")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("Tempo");


                    chart1.append("g")         // Add the Y Axis
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .style("font-size", "12px");


        chart1.append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 70 - margin.left)
                .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
                .attr("dy", "1em")
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text("Valore");


            chart1.append("path")       
             .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", valueline(data))
                .style("stroke-width", 5);

          chart1.append("path")         
                .attr("class", "line")
                        .style("stroke", "#6f6f6f")
                .attr("d", valueline2(data))
                .style("stroke-width", 5);
                ;

        //tooltip line 1

        chart1.selectAll("dot")    
                .data(data)         
            .enter().append("circle")                               
                .attr("r", 5.5)
                .style("fill", "#fff8ee")    
                   .style("opacity", 1)      // set the element opacity
            .style("stroke", "#f93")    // set the line colour
         .style("stroke-width", 3.5) 

                .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })       
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })     
                .on("mouseover", function(d) {   
        d3.select(this).attr("r", 8).style("fill", "#f93").style("opacity", 1) ; 


                    div.transition()        
                        .duration(70)      
                        .style("opacity", .8)

                         ;      
                    div .html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 64) + "px"); 
                    })                  
                .on("mouseout", function(d) {     
                d3.select(this).attr("r", 5.5).style("fill", "#fff8ee"); 
                    div.transition()        
                        .duration(200)      
                        .style("opacity", 0) });



        //tooltio line2
        chart1.selectAll("dot")    
                .data(data)         
            .enter().append("circle")                               
                .attr("r", 5.5)
                .style("fill", "#fff8ee")    
                   .style("opacity", 1)      // set the element opacity
            .style("stroke", "#6f6f6f")    // set the line colour
         .style("stroke-width", 3.5) 

                .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })       
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.open); })     
                .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
                    d3.select(this).attr("r", 8).style("fill", "#6f6f6f").style("opacity", 1) ; //il punto cambia al mousover (bellissmo)

                    div.transition()        
                        .duration(70)      
                        .style("opacity", .7)
                        .style("border", "1px");      
                    div .html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 64) + "px");    
                    })                  
                .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
               d3.select(this).attr("r", 5.5).style("fill", "#fff8ee");  

                    div.transition()        
                        .duration(200)      
                        .style("opacity", 0);   
                });



        //title

                chart1.append("text")
                .attr("x", (width / 6))             
                .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
                .style("font-size", "20px") 
                .style("text-decoration", "none")  
                .text("Modello 1: Serie (pochi dati) ");
        });

        </script>

            </html>
```